# Calculating $\lim_{x\to\infty} (\sin\frac{1}{x}+\cos\frac{1}{x})^x$ without l'Hopital

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

> Calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty} (\sin\frac{1}{x}+\cos\frac{1}{x})^x$  without using l'Hopital's rule.

I attempted pulling something out to get a limit that resembles $e$, this gave me:

$$\sin^x\frac{1}{x}(1+\frac{1}{\tan\frac{1}{x}})^x=\sin^x\frac{1}{x}\bigg[(1+\frac{1}{\tan\frac{1}{x}})^{\tan\frac{1}{x}}\bigg]^{\frac{x}{\tan\frac{1}{x}}}$$

But then the first part goes to $0$ and the exponent goes to infinity, and I'm kinda stumped.

Comment: We seem to get a lot of questions about computing various limits "without l'Hopital's rule." Seems easier to just go ahead and use l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @anomaly I agree, but I'm preparing for a test, and the instructions say "without l'Hopital's rule"

Comment: I figured that; my point is that it's silly to artificially prevent students from using a simple (to both use and prove) tool that's perfectly suited to this sort of problem.